# NamedPipeServerStream between C# and Python processes and RedirectStandardOutput not showing anything

Tags: python, c#, pipe

I'm opening a myProcess to run a python script, since the argument arg1 I'm providing the script is large, I am instead opening a NamedPipeServerStream in a PipeServer class and trying to connect myProcess to both redirect it's output to the visual studio output window, as well as have it write a response to the pipe.

However I'm not seeing anything from python being written to the output, and my code will hang on `response = server.ReadPipe();` forever awaiting something.

See below my C# function that opens a python process and calls the PipeServer class' functions. See below that the PipeServer functions, and below that my python code.

Does anyone have a suggestion that could help? I'm having a hard time even debugging because nothing from the python side is visible.

```
    private string RunPy(double[] arg1)
    {
        PipeServer server = new PipeServer(pipeName);

        string python = @"C:\Users\MR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe"; // Python path.
        string myPythonApp = @"C:\Users\MR\PycharmProjects\UA2Ttrainer\predictsingle.py"; // Python script.
        string argString = string.Join(",", arg1);
        string output;
        string response = "null";

        // Python process
        ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(python);

        myProcessStartInfo.Arguments = myPythonApp + " " + pipeName;
        Debug.WriteLine(myProcessStartInfo.Arguments);
        myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

        Process myProcess = new Process();
        myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;


        // Handle the OutputDataReceived event
        myProcess.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
        {
            // Write the output to the Visual Studio Output window
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Data);
        };

        // Handle the ErrorDataReceived event
        myProcess.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
        {
            // Write the error output to the Visual Studio Output window
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Data);
        };

        myProcess.Start();
        // Begin reading the output and error output
        myProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
        myProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();

        server.Start();

        // output = myProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        // string error = myProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

        // Send our data to python and read a response
        server.SendMessage(string.Join(",", arg1));
        response = server.ReadPipe();

        Debug.WriteLine($"Response: {response}");

        server.Stop();
        myProcess.WaitForExit();

        return response;
        
    }
```

PipeServer:

```
public class PipeServer
{
    private NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer;

    public PipeServer(string pipeName)
    {
        pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipeName, PipeDirection.InOut);
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        // Start listening for connections
        pipeServer.WaitForConnection();
    }

    public void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pipeServer);
        sw.WriteLine(string.Join(",", message));
        sw.Flush();
    }

    public string ReadPipe()
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeServer);
        string message = "null";
        if (sr.ReadLine != null)
        {
            message = sr.ReadLine();
        }
        return message;
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        pipeServer.Disconnect();
        pipeServer.Dispose();
    }
```

Python:

```
# Get run arguments
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pipeName = sys.argv[1]
    pipePath = f'\\\\.\\pipe\\{pipeName}'
    while True:
        try:
            print("Pipe connecting")
            pipe = open(pipePath, 'r+')  # Open the pipe with read/write mode
            break
        except FileNotFoundError:
            time.sleep(1)
    print("Pipe connected")
    receiveddata = list(map(int, pipe.read().split(",")))
    # Write a response to the pipe
    pipe.write(f"Received array of length {len(receiveddata)}")
    pipe.flush()  # Make sure the response is written
    pipe.close()  # Explicitly close the file
    print("received data: ", receiveddata)
    exit()
```

Comment: `if (sr.ReadLine != null) { message = sr.ReadLine(); }` why are you doing this? Just do `return sr.ReadLine();` note by the way that `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` need `using`, and that you should construct them with the `leaveOpen: true` parameter.